# Dlib android real time face recognition issue

Tags: android, git, real-time, face-recognition, dlib

Dlib is a library that permits extracting face landmarks from pictures or in real time through the phone camera.
It is available here : https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android

I have an issue that i didn't succeed to detect landmarks in real time through the camera using the sample project in the Git.
Can someone help me please ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Mobile Vision framework for facial landmark detection in android